# How to download an archive of Facebook messages without tampering, so they can be used in court?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Does anyone know how to download an archive of Facebook messages from one person dated September 24th to recent?

The following message is merely an example:

[image]

These archives must show they are directly from Facebook without tampering otherwise they cannot be used in court. All the lawyer needs is a way to confirm that it is indeed a conversation that was sent on Facebook, that way she can use it in her case. I know in Facebook Settings you can download your Facebook Data. However I was not told directly if she can use it for her case.

Comment: There's a lot of extra information here.  Try to hone it down to the bare essentials of what we can help you with, Facebook software-wise.

Comment: Usually when I print webpages out it'll print the url and website title. In addition I summarized the question the best of my ability. 

May I ask why there's two down votes? What exactly am I in violation of?

Comment: I don't know that you're in "violation" of anything. But I do see a big wall of text and it's not clear what the issue is. Perhaps you should cull all the unnecessary background.

Comment: #pnuts that would be the best option however there has to be a paper that confirms that those printed messages came directly from Facebook without being tampered with. Otherwise the lawyer can not use them in court.

Comment: I revised/summarized the question once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way as described at https://www.facebook.com/safety/groups/law/guidelines/ is to go to your security settings under the account section and you can download a .zip file with your information; your messages will be in html format, but they will be print-friendly.

https://m.facebook.com/help/212802592074644?refid=69